# Sum values in a comma-separated string

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has a column called QTY in which most of the values are already summed, but a few are several integers separated by commas. How can I replace those rows with the sums of the values?

I have:

```
ID    Name    QTY
1     Abc     2
2     Bac     3
3     Cba     2, 4, 5, 8
4     Bcb     4, 1
```

Desired result:

```
ID    Name    QTY
1     Abc     2
2     Bac     3
3     Cba     19
4     Bcb     5
```

I've tried messing around with for loops a bit and using ifelse(), but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: I'm guessing QTY is a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a bit ugly but should work. Assuming column `QTY` is a character -

```
your_df$QTY_new <- sapply(strsplit(your_df$QTY, ", "), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for loops should be this way:

```
data <- data.table(ID = 1:4,
                   Name = c("Abc", "Bac", "Cba", "Bcb"),
                   QTY = c("2", "3", "2, 4, 5, 8", "4, 1"),
                   QTY2 = numeric(4))

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data$QTY2[i] <- sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(data$QTY[i]), ', '))))
}
```

and the resulting DF is:

```
   ID Name        QTY QTY2
1:  1  Abc          2    2
2:  2  Bac          3    3
3:  3  Cba 2, 4, 5, 8   19
4:  4  Bcb       4, 1    5
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function for solving your question. But let me explain how it works:

```
     sumInRow = function(row_value, split = ",") {
         # 1. split the values
         row_value = strsplit(row_value, split = split)

         # 2. Convert them to numeric and sum
         row_sum = sapply(row_value, function(single_row) {
              single_row = as.numeric(single_row)
              return(sum(single_row))
         })

         return(row_sum)
    }
```

The row_value, by default, will be a character because of the comma.
Then for each value we need to split them:

```
    row_value = strsplit(row_value, split = split)
```

But it will return a list contain the split for all element in *row_value*, don't worry we'll use it later.

```
    row_sum = sapply(row_value, function(single_row) {
          single_row = as.numeric(single_row)
          return(sum(single_row))
    })
```

Sapply function works as an interator, for each element of the list we'll use the following function: convert to numeric and return the sum of them.

[EDIT_1]

To use if you have to call:

```
sumInRow(<your data frame>$QYT)
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`,  We split the 'QTY' column by the delimiter `,` to expand the rows (`separate_rows`), grouped by 'ID', 'Name', get the `sum` of the 'QTY'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(QTY, convert = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Name) %>% 
  summarise(QTY = sum(QTY))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
#     ID Name    QTY
#  <int> <chr> <int>
#1     1 Abc       2
#2     2 Bac       3
#3     3 Cba      19
#4     4 Bcb       5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Name = c("Abc", "Bac", "Cba", "Bcb"), 
QTY = c("2", "3", "2, 4, 5, 8", "4, 1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -4L))
```